# Which is better for running background processes . Php Cron or Linux Daemon?

Tags: php, linux, perl, cron, daemon

Which technique is better to be used for running background processes on linux server.

Php Cron or Linux Daemon ?

May be written in perl .etc. Just want some advice in view of performance and stability ?

Comment: What "php cron"? There are lots of implementations of job schedulers in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your needs. In most cases, cron-run PHP (or Perl or bash or any) scripts are way easier to debug, because they can be run independent from cron, and cron already provides the time control you would otherwise have to provide yourself.

Daemons are useful if you want to encapsulate your functionality into a single program, for example if it switches between different states and the like. But in most cases you will have to find a way to ensure that your daemon is still running.

I am not talking about server daemons, because thats not achievable with cron-triggered PHP scripts, and is a complex topic on its own.

Answer (score 2):

The advantage of daemons is that they are persistent, so 1) they can wait for external requests, and 2) there's no load-up time.

The advantage of cron jobs is that 1) they are easier to debug, and 2) they naturally recover from unexpected termination.